# Перестали работать pci устройства в Linux после замены процессора

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, elementary-os

Поменял процессор с g2020 на i5-3470, после чего отвалились видеокарта gt1030 и wi-fi адаптер pci-e в Elementary OS (Ubuntu 18.04). В списке устройств lspci присутствуют, определены правильно, но системой не используются, как-будто не установлены драйвера. На Windows 10 все работает как надо. В чем может быть проблема? Может быть какие-то микрокоды проца нужно обновить или еще что-то в этом роде? Спасибо заранее за ответы.

Вывод lspci -nk -vv для устройств, которые перестали работать:

```
01:00.0 0300: 10de:1d01 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: 1462:8c98
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Region 1: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 3: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
Region 5: I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

03:00.0 0280: 14e4:43a0 (rev 03)
Subsystem: 14e4:0619
Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
Region 0: Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
Region 2: Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=2M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: для начала удалите если стоит nouveau и поставьте nvidia драйвер, wi-fi - broadcom наверное? его драйвер не вручную ставили?

Comment: да, wi-fi broadcom, после установки системы какие-то манипуляции с драйверов проводил, чтобы заработал.

Comment: Приложите вывод `lspci -nk -vv` для тех устройств, которые не работают.

Comment: депмод и апдейт-инитрамфс

Comment: depmod и update-initramfs не помогли, переустановка драйвера nvidia тоже ничего не поменяла.

Comment: @ArtyomPopov, перед установкой nvidia, nouveau надо сначала вырезать, это обычно целая песня, для конкретной системы надо в инете найти инструкцию